ImportError: cannot import name 'PlaceholderRelationField' from 'cms.models.fields'
I created new Django CMS project and tried to install also plugin Djangocms-blog after installation server is not running with this error
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\djangocms_alias\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderRelationField
ImportError: cannot import name 'PlaceholderRelationField' from 'cms.models.fields' (C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\newvis\venv\lib\site-packages\cms\models\fields.py)


I tried different version of django-cms and djangocms-blog but still getting this error. How I can solve this problem?

What Django version are you using?

In first time I used last version (4.1.1) and get this error. After I tried with versions 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 but still get this error after install djangocms-blog

Can you share your project tree?

I imagine you're on django-cms 4 and the official djangocms-blog release doesn't support it. Support is in development however and you might be best joining the django-cms discord for support on this; https://discord.gg/A3yQMM8W
